# gravity forms api to (re)send notification emails

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am using the [Gravity Forms API](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/API_Functions) to manually add entries to a form I've created. According to the docs, the triggers that would normally send the notification emails to both admins and users are not fired:

> Intended to be used for importing an entry object. The usual hooks that are triggered while saving entries are not fired here.

Does anyone know how I could programmatically trigger these notifications?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for GFCommon::send_notification. There's a [tutorial](https://gravityplus.pro/how-to/programmatically-trigger-gravity-forms-notification/) with a code example.

Comment: Short and sweet! Thanks!

Comment: I found this implementation a lot easier to understand https://github.com/envex/gravity-forms-skeleton/blob/master/gravity-forms-skeleton.php#L145

Comment: Can someone give me some example to implement this? It's exactly what I need but I'm a wordpress noob.

Comment: @Naomi - How can I use your tutorial from a stand alone php file which on same server but in different directory and does not have wordpress available in that file..   Thanks